# Detect Visual Composer

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to detect if a WordPress page is using Visual Composer?

I have 2 different page templates:

1. Default template for regular pages.
2. Template for visual composer pages.

I'm hoping there is a way to detect if a user is using visual composer to build the page instead of relying on the user selecting the visual composer template each time.

Is there a way to detect what page is being built and then assign a template based on that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can detect if visual composer is enabled for a post. It's stored in the `_wpb_vc_js_status` post meta attribute.

```
$vc_enabled = get_post_meta($post_id, '_wpb_vc_js_status', true);
```

Note that a post can still contain the visual composer shortcodes, even when visual composer editing is not currently enabled. For example, if I setup a page with visual composer and then revert back to the normal editor, `_wpb_vc_js_status` will be false.

Comment: $vc_enabled = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wpb_vc_js_status', true) === 'true'; //Is better since wp store "false" as a string in postmeta, which translate to boolean true (since its not empty) if u enable and disable VC editor.

Answer (score 12):

**only for WPBakery Page Builder**

Actually, `_wpb_vc_js_status` since 4.8 is not correct, because it was not used anymore. The simplest way to check if page is using wpbakery - it is check for `vc_row` shortcode in content.

```
$post = get_post();
if ( $post && preg_match( '/vc_row/', $post->post_content ) ) {
    // Visual composer works on current page/post
}
```

Comment: Very good answer. Thank you for this. It worked like a charm in my theme to add a condition for adding a class when WPBakery Page Builder is active on the page (`vc_row`).

Answer (score 4):

You can detect with is_plugin_active:

```
if ( is_plugin_active( 'js_composer/js_composer.php' ) ) {
     //your code here
}
```

Comment: My only warning about using this method is that it will not work if the plugin directory `js_composer` is renamed. While this is not typical, I have seen at least one major theme use a customized version on WPBakery and renamed the directory. There may be other reasons that a user might rename the plugin dir. Most of those reasons can probably be addressed in a more appropriate way, but it can happen. One might consider `if( defined( 'WPB_VC_VERSION' ) ) { ... }` or `if( class_exists( 'Vc_Manager' ) )` instead.

Comment: Well this worked a charm, i've never rename plugings folder name as the creator places them. So this helped not to crash my site. :D

Answer (score 1):

```
if( defined( 'WPB_VC_VERSION' ) ) { ... }
```

works like a charm. I was searching for a possibility to hide the Nag screen that occurs when you get the WPBakery Page Builder as a bundeled plugin with a commercial theme to avoid customer's confusion. In case someone could need that snippet:

```
// hide nag screen of WP Bakery Visual composer if found
if( defined( 'WPB_VC_VERSION' ) ) {
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['vchideactivationmsg_vc11'])) {
        setcookie('vchideactivationmsg', '1', strtotime('+3 years'), '/');
        setcookie('vchideactivationmsg_vc11',  WPB_VC_VERSION, strtotime('+3 years'), '/');
     }
}
```

Hook that into admin_init and you're good to go!

Comment: This is a good check to see if the plugin is enabled but it doesn't answer the question.