# Load visual composer shortcode above page content

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

this is my first time using visual composer on a theme I am creating, I am facing a challenge which is loading visual composer element above the page content , I mean above the main content, giving it a full width, what I mean is that when ever I drag and drop VC element on a page it goes inside the main page i want it to be outside the main page content. I contacted support and they said visual composer element would show anywhere there is `<?php the_content(); ?>` is found.

I saw a code online where I can check if visual composer is placed on a page, if yes it has a separate format created for it (mainly to hide sidebar), and if null it uses the default page template which has main page content and sidebar.

my question is, does any one know how to implement the code , i found the code in this question on stack overflow. [Detect Visual Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312067/detect-visual-composer)

Or does any one has ideal on how to make all drag and drop element stay on top the page and not in the page context.

Comment: Do you mean a header?

Comment: I mean i have want to load it above the <?php content(); ?>, and i tink why is nt working is because vissual composer loads anywhere it sees, <?php content() ?>. Do u have any other approach than this ?

Comment: I've been struggling with something like this. i'm trying to put VC contents into page's header and footer. Looks like you have to deal directly with you theme or use any plugin that manipulates such areas.

However, answering your question, I found so far that VC really only applies to `<?php content() ?>`.